# How to access refs with react-sortable-hoc, withref

Tags: reactjs, react-sortable-hoc

I tried using the "withref" in `react-sortable-hoc` and I need to have my parent component access the children components for some calls I need to invoke on the parent side. I'm not sure where to even call the `getWrappedInstance`, which seems to be providing access to the children component.

I'm aware of [forwarding](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) but it seems like `react-sortable-hoc` have a different implementation.

To be more specific, I have something like this:

```
const SortableItem = SortableElement((props) => (
  <div className="sortable">
    <MyElement {...props}/>
  </div>
), {withRef: true});
```

```
const MidasSortableContainer = SortableContainer(({ children }: { children: any }) => {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
}, {withRef: true});
```

```
<MySortableContainer
  axis="xy"
  onSortEnd={this.onSortEnd}
  useDragHandle
>{chartDivs}</MySortableContainer>
```

Before I wrapped in HOC, I was able to do the following

```
const chartDivs = elements.map(({childName}, index) => {
      return <MyElement
              ref={r => this.refsCollection[childName] = r}
...
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to achieve the same after wrapping with HOC? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The key is from source code: https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc/blob/master/src/SortableElement/index.js#L82

`getWrappedInstance()` function.

I guess, after is your origin code:

```
// this is my fake MyElement Component
class MyElement extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div className='my-element-example'>This is test my element</div>
    )
  }
}

// this is your origin ListContainer Component
class OriginListContainer extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const elements = [
      { childName: 'David' },
      { childName: 'Tom' }
    ]

    return (
      <div className='origin-list-container'>
        {
          elements.map(({ childName }, index) => {
            return <MyElement key={index} ref={r => this.refsCollection[childName] = r} />
          })
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Now you import `react-sortable-hoc`

```
import { SortableElement, SortableContainer } from 'react-sortable-hoc'
```

First you create new `Container Component`:

```
const MySortableContainer = SortableContainer(({ children }) => {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
})
```

Then make MyElement be **sortable**

```
/**
 * Now you have new MyElement wrapped by SortableElement
 */
const SortableMyElement = SortableElement(MyElement, {
  withRef: true
})
```

**Here is import:**

- You should use `SortableElement(MyElement, ...` to `SortableElement((props) => <MyElement {...props}/>`, second plan will make `ref` prop be `null`
- `{ withRef: true }` make your can get ref by `getWrappedInstance`

OK, now you can get your before ref like after **`ref={r => this.refsCollection[childName] = r.getWrappedInstance()} />`**

Here is full code:

```
const MySortableContainer = SortableContainer(({ children }) => {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
})

/**
 * Now you have new MyElement wrapped by SortableElement
 */
const SortableMyElement = SortableElement(MyElement, {
  withRef: true
})

class ListContainer extends React.Component {
  refsCollection = {}

  componentDidMount () {
    console.log(this.refsCollection)
  }

  render () {
    const elements = [
      { childName: 'David' },
      { childName: 'Tom' }
    ]

    return (
      <MySortableContainer
        axis="xy"
        useDragHandle
      >
        {
          elements.map(({ childName }, index) => {
            return (
              <SortableMyElement
                index={index}
                key={index}
                ref={r => this.refsCollection[childName] = r.getWrappedInstance()} />
            )
          })
        }
      </MySortableContainer>
    )
  }
}
```

**Append**

Ehh...

before I said: *You should use `SortableElement(MyElement, ...` to `SortableElement((props) => <MyElement {...props}/>`, second plan will make `ref` prop be `null`*

if you really wanna use callback function, you can use like after:

```
const SortableMyElement = SortableElement(forwardRef((props, ref) => <MyElement ref={ref} {...props} />), {
  withRef: true
})
```

But here **NOT** the true use of forwardRef

---

Ehh... choose your wanna.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer. I see the `ref='listContainer'` is how you name it (wasn't clear from reading the source code because I wasn't familiar with how refs work in general). However, I am still not sure how to achieve what I want, which is to access the refs of the children (wrapped by `SortableElement`) from the parent (wrapped by `SortableComponent`). Thanks! I'm going to update my question to make it more clear. Thanks!